# An energy consumption problem

Tags: operating-systems, discrete-mathematics

We want to show one schedule of jobs consumes less energy than another one. For example, there are two schedules A and B. Both the schedules A and B schedule two jobs $j_1$ and $j_2$ with execution time $C_1$ and $C_2$. Schedule A schedules the two jobs with frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$ while schedule B schedules the two jobs with frequencies $f_3$ and $f_4$. The condition is that $f_1 < f_3$ and $f_2 > f_4$ and $f_3 \ne f_4$. Now how can we show that schedule A is consuming less energy than schedule B.

Let the energy consumption function is $C_1 \cdot {f_x}^2 + C_2 \cdot {f_y}^2$.

Comment: This isn't true. You can easily come up with a counterexample.

Comment: That means do I need to show that $f_3$ and $f_4$ don't lie between $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: This looks like a question of pure mathematics; you want to know whether $f_1<f_3$ and $f_2 >f_4$ and $f_3 \ne f_4$ implies $C_1 f_1^2 + C_2 f_2^2 < C_1 f_3^2 + C_2 f_4^2$.  Once it is formulated as a mathematics problem like this, I don't see any remaining computer science content here.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with computability, or distributed systems, for instance.